# Can a variable in data be computed based on other data?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I would like to have some of the `data` variables computed based on some other variables and follow their changes in the `Vue` instance. The natural solution

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#root',
  data: {
    a: 1,
    b: a + 1
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.3/vue.js"></script>

<div id="root">
  {{ a }} and {{ b }}
</div>
```

fails with `Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined`.

**Is it possible to use previously defined variables to create new ones on the fly?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Self-references in object literal declarations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literal-declarations)

Comment: `data: {
    a: 1,
    b: a + 1
  }` a is an var in data?

Comment: @JJJ: wouldn't the `init` part in the linked answer be calculated only once? I would like `b` to follow the changes of `a`.

Comment: That you can't do. `b` would have to be a function, or you'd need to set a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) for `b` but I don't know if  Vue supports that.

Comment: obj = new Vue(//stuff//)   then access it by  obj.data.a   and obj.data.b

Comment: (Or maybe Vue provides another way to do it, I'm not familiar with it.)

Comment: @JJJ: I just found the right approach for Vue (and posted as an answer). Thanks for the hints (and the answer is not a duplicate but I am not sure about how to advertise that)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to use [computed values](https://vuejs.org/guide/computed.html), `b` will be accessible the same way as if it was declared in `data`:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#root',
  data: {
    a: 1
  },
  computed: {
    // a computed getter
    b: function() {
      // `this` points to the vm instance
      return this.a + 1
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.3/vue.js"></script>

<div id="root">
  {{ a }} and {{ b }}
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
var x;
new Vue(x = {
   el: '#root',
   data: {
     a: 1,
     b: () =>  x.data.a + 1
   }
})
```